# Document is empty in Jasper Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

i am using a oracle data adapter. when i put my query in sql developer it returns value. but in jasper it shows document is empty. is their any way to check if my data adapter is working properly or not? 
i am new in jasper studio. if any setting need to change please mention. i am using oracle 11G express edition.

here is my jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.11.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.11.0-0c4056ccaa4d25a5a8c45672d2f764ea3498bebb  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Cherry_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="13acf49e-4913-4d1b-bccc-113817ad15d1">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="KHALID"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select c.productname, sum(b.quantity)
from orders a, orderdetails b, products c
where a.orderid = b.orderid
and b.PRODUCT = c.id
group by c.productname]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PRODUCTNAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="PRODUCTNAME"/>
    </field>
    <field name="SUM(B.QUANTITY)" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SUM(B.QUANTITY)"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="132" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="456" y="0" width="99" height="132" uuid="97705585-a0b5-4ec7-86f3-ae10c220e6af"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["cherry.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="451" height="95" backcolor="#000000" uuid="6c6ca4e1-17cd-4913-93d6-5e670ea9ae8a"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="66" uuid="a2a2cac8-5a7d-4487-8c54-dab235ce4e21"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry Title]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="157" y="66" width="249" height="29" uuid="8978eac3-c578-41c9-837e-48d2b0184642"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry SubTitle]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="100" width="451" height="32" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CC0000" uuid="e3c14156-5b51-4201-918b-97fdc012e5d4"/>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="307" y="12" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="5c3301e7-a737-4c59-8a2f-a6c79fd1adb8"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="26" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="0" y="7" width="277" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="a6b37150-9bee-492a-b969-f034f64edf4c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="e1446586-9fcf-432d-9dd5-955ccb125ee4"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCTNAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="277" y="7" width="277" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="6d1296a7-fb7c-46ca-9371-77d96da01824">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="dd4b0dcc-1ffd-4aa0-9af2-c6c23bcffe7d"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SUM(B.QUANTITY)]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="18" uuid="b50221b5-8254-440b-8c6f-1f0b138c9259"/>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="277" height="18" uuid="3c5fe24a-0a12-4767-98ee-528641a8400b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="e1446586-9fcf-432d-9dd5-955ccb125ee4"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCTNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="277" y="0" width="277" height="18" uuid="f11c3ade-0bb6-4270-820f-639e51664491">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="dd4b0dcc-1ffd-4aa0-9af2-c6c23bcffe7d"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUM(B.QUANTITY)}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1" uuid="1133a906-5b71-476e-9f3e-bc97c97058c1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="555" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#000000" uuid="729c3539-f946-4d0e-a0a7-bda2815ea1b0"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="513" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4834e99c-7f6c-485a-b098-50e5187f2ab4"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="433" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9825b46e-76f1-469a-abb8-a1cc27aad685"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="137d38c7-1a83-4fc5-b156-9d5f1b1a0ddc"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me once and I solved it confirmed the changes and it was not bringing data, in oracle run:

commit;